# hover(function(){ Not selecting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get parent li to display children when hovered over. here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

      $(".menu").hover(function(){
        var target = $(this).parent().children(".sub-menu > li  a");
        $(target).slideToggle(800);
      });


    })
```

using this html, hovering over "stage 2" would unhide assets and property, hovering over stage 1, would hide assets and property but reveal Methodology and acquisitions.

```
<ul id="menu-sidebarnav" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="drawer menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-51">
    <a href="/stage-1/">stage 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53">
            <a href="/opportunity/methodology/">Methodology</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52">
            <a href="/opportunity/acquisitions/">Acquisitions </a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-54" class="drawer menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-54">
<a href="/stage-2/">stage 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58">
             <a href="/competence/assets/">Assets</a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57">
             <a href="/competence/property/">Property</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the hover for the `li` element then toggle the `.sub-menu` item which is inside the `li` so

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".menu > li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(800);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8j8m2yks/)

Comment: Arun, how would one introduce a delay prior to the toggle effect? the result on my end is kind of jumpy.